# multi-objective optimization with optim (in R)

Tags: r, optimization

I have little background in mathematics and am trying to write a multi-objective optimization function.

I have the following 3 vectors:

```
A = 0.4122487 0.3861316 0.3160613 0.2949684
B = 0.1407469 0.1828053 0.2088941 0.2143583
C = 0.2966363 0.1947112 0.1664350 0.1543946
```

My goal is the following: to find at which value X my requirements are best met: 1) minimize A, 2) maximize B and 3) maximize C.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
fun <- function(weights,A,B,C){
   fit = sum((weights[1] * A +
        weights[2] * B +
        weights[3] * C))
    return(fit)
}

# the weight of A (positive, since I want to minimise A)
Wa = 1
# the weight of B (negative, since I want to maximise B)
Wb = -0.5
# the weight of C (negative, since I want to maximise C)
Wc = -1.5
result <- optim(weights=c(Wa,Wb,Wc), fn = fun)
```

Here are the results:

```
result$par = 2.365022e+44 -1.697108e+44 -9.150244e+43
result$value = -5.343856e+44
```

Is my implementation correct? How do I interpret these results? My understanding is very limited, but instinctively these numbers seem out of proportion compared to the range of my initial vectors...

Comment: why the downvote on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

Implementation fails the following way: `par[1] * A` is a vector of four elements, so is `par[2] * B`  and `par[3] * [C]`. Your function `fun` first calculates sum of three vectors and then sums elements of it.

Function `optim()` tries to find such parameters of vector `par` that return return value of your function is lowest possible. That means it maximises the **sum** of vector A multiplied by `par[1]` and minimises **sums** of vectors B and C multiplied by `par[2]` and `par[3]`.

The answer would be quite similar when you just maximise `par[1]` and minimise `par[2]` and `par[3]` with no other constraints. Mathematical answer would be infinities, but it seems function `optim()` reaches maximum computable values which are for example 2.36 *10^44 (*scientific notation*).

This way it does not meet your needs and it needs to be implemented other way.

#### Solution:

It is hard to define what you really want to do: are A, B, C discrete vectors or they are supposed represent functions, as they are plotted? Other words your solution should use exact values from these vectors or something between? After providing such information a scheme of possible solution to that problem may be found somewhere.

[edit: added solution below]

There is a stack overflow question for discrete optimisation using `optim()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110848/how-to-optimize-for-integer-parameters-and-other-discontinuous-parameter-space). But i think it is too big tank to kill a mouse this time.

I would calculate a value of a function in Data Frame and use `max()` to find best choice:

```
# sample data:
A <- c(0.4122487, 0.3861316, 0.3160613, 0.2949684)
B <- c(0.1407469, 0.1828053, 0.2088941, 0.2143583)
C <- c(0.2966363, 0.1947112, 0.1664350, 0.1543946)
df <- data.frame(A = A, B = B, C = C)

#solution
df$fun <- df$A - df$B - df$C 
head(df)
df[df$fun == max(df$fun),]
```

You can also find some tutorials for using `optim()` at google if you just want to learn some stuff.

Comment: Great answer! Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68280857/r-x-probs-outside-0-1